# Expo - React Native / Firebase app, APK working different than on Expo go app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo, apk

I have built an app with Expo & firebase and its working with the expo go app. I ran "expo build:android" and got my APK file. The app loads and my Login and Register pages work as expected. However once logged in, none of my Firestore data loads and buttons do not work.

edit: Checked loggs and found that data is loading, just components not rendering as well as buttons not working.

I checked Firestore and the "Registered" user is being saved...

Auth and Firestore do seem to be working properly

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Also, what part of the app if any needs to be hosted?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the code that is not working as intended?

Comment: i have the same issue, do you find a solution for it ?

Comment: @AliMohammad I have not yet. Very strange. Auth and writing the user to Firestore works, but reading does not, and buttons don't work...  Lmk if you find something

Comment: yes i found the problem. go to firebase console => settings => add app => select android app then download google-services file => add it to app.josn like that "{
  "expo": {
    "android": {
      "package": "com.mypackage.coolapp",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
    }
  }
}"

Comment: if that solve the problem tell me please to make it as answer

Comment: @AliMohammad I have that set up already.

Comment: Just looked at some logs and found that all the data is being read. and logged to the console. but isn't rendering. also as mentioned earlier buttons aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

What [@Ali Mohammad wrote in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71672841/expo-react-native-firebase-app-apk-working-different-than-on-expo-go-app/72114929#comment126804746_71672841) is working for me. Here is their comment, with improved formatting:

Go to the *Firebase Console* > *Settings* > *Add app* > select *Android app* and then download the `google-services` file > add it to your `app.json` like:

```
"{ "expo": { "android": { "package": "com.mypackage.coolapp", "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json" } } }"
```

Comment: Thank!  But Firebase is working fine by me.. Like I answered Ali, the data is being logged so Firebase is not the issue here.  But thanks for trying!